# Voice does not record when playing video in video view in android

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

I am developing an application where I want to start recording voice on button click, and also want to start playing video in video view at the same time.
now the app works on android 4.2 and android 5.1 but does not work on the latest device like android 7.0.
Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    Button start,stop,play;
Boolean recording=false;
String press_value="exit";



private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
    boolean let_start_recording=true;

    ImageView startIV,profileIV;

    boolean recording_is_in_progress=false;
    VideoView vv ;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    RelativeLayout mainRel;

    ///new media player
    String AudioSavePathInDevice = null;
      MediaRecorder mediaRecorder ;
      Random random ;
      String RandomAudioFileName = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
      public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;
      MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;




@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    startIV=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    profileIV=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.your_video_view);
    mainRel=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_rel);


    recording_is_in_progress=false;
    StopAnimation();

    profileIV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
        if(let_start_recording)
            {
                let_start_recording=false;
                startIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.recorder_stop_circle);
                startRecording();
                recording_is_in_progress=true;
                StartAnimation();

            }
            else
            {
                let_start_recording=true;
                startIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.recorder_start_circle);
                stopRecording();
                recording_is_in_progress=false;

                StopAnimation();//Stop Animation once we press button

            }
        }

    });

    //START & STOP  Recording
    startIV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
        if(let_start_recording)
            {
                let_start_recording=false;
                startIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.recorder_stop_circle);
                startRecording();
                recording_is_in_progress=true;
                StartAnimation();

            }
            else
            {
                let_start_recording=true;
                startIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.recorder_start_circle);
                stopRecording();
                recording_is_in_progress=false;

                StopAnimation();//Stop Animation once we press button

            }
        }

    });



    }//EOF Oncreate


//((((   START ANIMATION ))))
public void StartAnimation()
{

//  vv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    startIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mainRel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    profileIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);

       //Video Loop
    vv.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            vv.start(); //need to make transition seamless.
        }
    });

 //   Uri uri = Uri.parse(R.drawable.sheep_video);
    Uri uri= Uri.parse("android.resource://com.pac.myapp/raw/sheep_video");

    vv.setVideoURI(uri);
    vv.requestFocus();    
    vv.start();

    vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.sheep_video));


    vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
        {
            mp.setLooping(true);
          ///  showtoast("video compelted");
        }
    });

}

public void StopAnimation()
{
    if(vv.isPlaying())
        vv.stopPlayback();

    //vv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    startIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mainRel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    profileIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


}

private String getFilename()
{
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if (!file.exists()) 
    {
        file.mkdirs();
    }


    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String filename = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    filename="Voice "+filename+".wav";

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + filename);
    //return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".wav");
}

private void startRecording() 
{

     AudioSavePathInDevice =  getFilename();
          //   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + 
            //    CreateRandomAudioFileName(5) + "AudioRecording.3gp";

          MediaRecorderReady();

          try {
             mediaRecorder.prepare();
             mediaRecorder.start();
          } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          }

}

private void stopRecording() 
{
     mediaRecorder.stop();
}


   public void MediaRecorderReady(){
      mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
      mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
      mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
      mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
      mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);
   }


public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(recording_is_in_progress=true)
    {
        //if(recorder!=null)
         //stopRecording();
        finish();
    }
}
public void home(View v)
 {
//Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
//startActivity(i);
//finish();

  }
  public void voice_list(View v)
  {  
   if(recording_is_in_progress==false)
   {
   Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(),SavedVoiceList.class);
   startActivity(i);
   finish();
}

 }
  public void about_us(View v)
  {
//showtoast("status = "+recording_is_in_progress);

if(recording_is_in_progress==false)
{
   Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(),AboutUsActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
   finish();
 }
}
 public void showtoast(String str)
 {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }   
  }//EOF Activit
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to request a `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO` permission to be able to record it after Android 6 version.

please check [the document](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)